# If you access a key that does not exist, "illegal string offset"

Tags: php

About arrays.
From PHP 5.4, "illegal string offset" now appears when accessing a nonexistent key.

```
$array = [
  "name" => "John",
  "age" => "100",
];

echo $array["height"];   // PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'grade_master_id'
```

So, when you execute the above with PHP 5.3 or earlier, what will be output??

Comment: Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in on line ...............................

Comment: https://3v4l.org/5cN0A

Comment: Can't you try it for yourself and see for yourself? Although the use of short array syntax might give you syntax errors with versions of PHP < 5.4.0.... answer, it echoes a null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output would be

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in ...